# Where can I find the GCP service endpoints and quotas?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Googled enough and I'm not able to find on Google Cloud Platform documentation or anywhere else documentation similar to this one:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acm.html

I need a list for all GCP service endpoints. All I was able to find was this:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview

That provides the level of detail I'm after under:

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview#service_endpoints

Trying to build an uptime monitor and would like to query those service endpoints to present a dashboard for the operational standing of GCP services a project is consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure whether they're listed in a single HTML page.

You can use:

1. [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and then pick a service e.g. Cloud [Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/) and then [Service Endpoint(s)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/#service-endpoint)
2. `gcloud services list --format="value(config.name)" --available` will only yield the global endpoint and not regional as Cloud Run above.

I want to say that this should be in the platform's [discovery document(s)](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list) but they're not. As with #1 above you'd need to retrieve the discovery document for each service and then e.g. Cloud Run (v2) only returns the [global endpoint](https://run.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2).

Quotas are documented per service but you can also enumerate a project's quotas at:

```bash
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=${PROJECT}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm looking into this. Thru previous search I did stumble upon the API Explorer page and was expecting a regional endpoint for every service but mostly found global endpoints. Not sure how GCP manages to report on service impacts and availability regionally. I fond their status page and they do have an RSS feed:

https://status.cloud.google.com/

At the bottom....and thought I could start from there but disappointed that GCP hasn't done a better job at this.

Comment: You're welcome. Customers who are willing to pay for it will get more discrete status updates (It's been a few years since I left but I was part of the customer engineering team that provided this). The public status dashboard sucks. I wrote a parser for it but it would be much more useful if it were provided as an API and enabled reporting on the kind of granularity that you're seeking. It would be **really** helpful to be able to ask services about their health. I suspect, one challenge with this has been that, if the service is down, so are its meta endpoints **but** that's not an excuse.

Comment: I think it would be worth checking Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) for feature requests like this. Please post updates here and I'll pile on ;-) Do any of the cloud providers use out-of-band mechanisms for service dashboards? Doing so they'd be able to proactively report issues when chunks of their services are down.